# Unable to resolve the request "contactForm/sendMessage"

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm getting the following error and stack trace when submitting a form on a CraftCMS-3.7 website...

```
HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Page not found.
↵
Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException
Unable to resolve the request "contactForm/sendMessage".
...
```

- 

```
1. in [redacted]/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.phpat line 600
591592593594595596597598599600601602603604605606607608609            $route = implode('/', $request->getActionSegments());

        try {
            Craft::debug("Route requested: '$route'", __METHOD__);
            $this->requestedRoute = $route;
            return $this->runAction($route, $_GET);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->_unregisterDebugModule();
            if ($e instanceof InvalidRouteException) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException(Craft::t('yii', 'Page not found.'), $e->getCode(), $e);
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

2. in [redacted]/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php at line 266– craft\web\Application::_processActionRequest(craft\web\Request)
260261262263264265266267268269270271272                    throw new ForbiddenHttpException();
            }
        }
    }

    // If this is an action request, call the controller
    if (($response = $this->_processActionRequest($request)) !== null) {
        return $response;
    }

    // If we're still here, finally let Yii do it's thing.
    try {
        return parent::handleRequest($request);
3. in [redacted]/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 384– craft\web\Application::handleRequest(craft\web\Request)
4. in [redacted]/web/index.php at line 12– yii\base\Application::run()
6789101112// Load shared bootstrap
require '../bootstrap.php';

// Load and run Craft
/** @var craft\web\Application $app */
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH . '/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run()
```

And the HTML for the form...

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <h3>Schedule a Demo?</h3>

        <input id="vona" name="vona" type="text" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/thank-you">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" placeholder="Name" class="required" type="text" name="Name" value="">

        <label for="title">Company / Job Title</label>
        <input id="title" name="Company" placeholder="Company" class="required" type="text">

        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input id="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="required" type="text" name="Email" value="">
        <input id="hidden-email" name="Email" type="text" style="display:none;" autocomplete="off" />

        <textarea id="message" class="required" name="Message" placeholder="Message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="formSubmitBtn" />
    </form>
```

I thought that maybe I had the wrong value for the action input, but the same 'Unable to resolve the request "contactForm/sendMessage"' error message is returned regardless of what is listed as its value.

Comment: It might be helpful to know that this site was migrated from 2.x to 3.x then moved to a different host at one point.  The original live site doesn't have this same problem, but I can't find any errors or warnings that would indicate a problem with the migrated site.

Answer (score 3):

Your suspicion about the Craft 2 -> 3 migration is dead-on.

Yii changed how `action` attributes work between versions 1 and 2 (used in Craft 2 and 3, respectively), so you'll need to update `contactForm/sendMessage` to `contact-form/send-message`!

A couple more notes for your Craft 3 journey:

- There are some handy Twig helpers now to simplify these hidden inputs:

  - `{{ actionInput('my-controller/action-name') }}` ([Docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#actioninput))
  - `{{ redirectInput('some-path') }}` ([Docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#redirectinput))
  - `{{ hiddenInput('fieldName', myValue) }}` ([Docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#hiddeninput))
- CSRF protection should probably be enabled to reduce malicious/spam submissions.

Here's the relevant [upgrade documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html#request-params).